# How can i make a custom made textbox appear when hovering over a button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to make something like this:

[image]

Basically, I made the email button, and I want to make a custom textbox with text in it that slowly fades in when the mouse enters the Email button.
Now, I made the custom box like this:

```xml
<Style x:Key="AppearingTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3E82C4"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0F1C2B"/>
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Path Data="M0 0 30 0 50 -15 70 0 100 0 100 30 0 30z" Fill="#0F1C2B"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I am using it in the window like this:

```xml
<TextBox Style="{DynamicResource AppearingTextbox}" Height="30" Width="100" FontSize="14">
  aaaaaaaaaa
</TextBox>
```

However, all I get is the box filled with this grayish/black color and when I try to write in it nothing happens. I am a bit new to all of this so not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Also how would i make it appear or disappear on hover of another button?
I was thinking maybe of making a on mouseover effect on the Email button and link it somehow to the TextBox opacity... don't know how to do it yet..
Any help or insight would be appreciated.

```xml
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Ikona, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard >
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:00.3" AutoReverse="False">
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      <BeginStoryboard >
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:00.3" AutoReverse="False">
          <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

By adding this below the last closing of `<Setter>` tag in above code I managed to get the fade in and fade out animation on hover over the button.

I still have the issue of nothing being writen in my custom made box. Do i need to enable or change some property to get it to work? I have a feeling that the "Fill" is the problem here..but do not know what to do about it.

Comment: Ok, i managed to make it to work with the hover in and out. Works perfectly now. The only thing that i dont get how to do is write in the Box! Nothing is being displayed in my custom made box, and i don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="100" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="SomeButton"></Button>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="200" Background="Red" Opacity="0" Text="Some TextBox">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeButton, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard >
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01" AutoReverse="True">
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:01"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

The TextBox's Style simply says to watch for the Button's IsMouseOver property and when it is set to true to fade in in 1s. When the condition is false the TextBox fades out in 1s (AutoReverse="True")

Comment: So what happens when the user's mouse moves to focus the TextBox and the Button loses MouseOver?

Comment: @ChrisW. He's apparently only trying to display a text on mouseover of the Button, like a tooltip, not allow any user input. A TextBlock would be far more logical in this case or at least set the IsReadOnly TextBox's DP to true

Comment: Ooooh I didn't actually look at his stuff, I see what you mean now. Hell if that's the case I'd just use a templated ToolTip to meet the visual requirement and to ensure you don't run into ZIndex issues and the popup placement is always visible regardless of its location on the screen.

Comment: Yes, only mouse over, and the user gets info on what it is. After the button looses focus then id dissapears again. Ok, so, TextBlock, instead of TextBox. Ill look into it, then get back here.  What do you mean by ToolTip @ChrisW.?

Comment: I just looked it over..err..textblock doesnt have a Template property..so..how am i suppose to make the box look like in the picture? @nkoniishvt

Comment: Also @nkoniishvt With your code the box that displays according to your code blinks every 1 sec. I want it to stay visible while the button is hovered over and fades out when the mouse leaves the button. I made it stay by setting the Autoreverse to False. But cant get it to work on MouseLeave

Comment: @ChrisW. Indeed your way is better. :)
IvanHorvatin you need to set the DataTrigger.ExitActions in this case

Comment: Thanks, i tried it. And managed to get everything working! Thanks a bunch people!

Answer (score 1):

Just another option to describe what I meant by tooltip, you could do something like this. Just thrown together quick in notepad so you'll probably want to tweak it if you decide to go this route.

```
<Button Content="Blah" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="Blah Blah Blah" ToolTipService.Placement="Center">
   <Button.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                  <Grid Margin="0,60,0,0">
                     <Path Data="M0 0 30 0 50 -15 70 0 100 0 100 30 0 30z" Fill="#3E82C4" Stretch="Fill"/>
                     <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,8"/>
                  </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Comment: I'll take a look at it now. Just one question regarding the animation. Nkoniishvt used the animation, but it only blinks in an out on hover. What im trying to acomplish is it fade's in on hover and stays visible until the mouse leaves the button. As in a reminder, or info for the user to know what that button does.

Comment: Yea if you want entrance/exit animations you'll have to build them in to whatever you do.